# Stacking Feast on Cho`Gath with minions?

Tags: league-of-legends

How much should I be building Feast stacks on minions when playing AP Cho`Gath? Let's assume I am playing solo top, against a tough counter, and I've also got 10% cooldown reduce.

I'm just not sure if the benefit outweighs the risk (not having Feast up when needed to kill a champ).

Would I ever considering doing this at all during late game? Or only laning phase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Tanky Cho'Gath

Cho'Gath isn't a killer.

What I mean by this is that his role on a normal team comp is not to have the most damage. His mid and ADC allies should be able to kill all the enemies.

Cho'Gath wants to be in the middle of a group of enemies, being as annoying as possible. The more distracting you are, the less your opponents attack your carries, and the more time your carries have to kill people.

Having Feast stacks makes you more unkillable. It is almost always worth killing a minion to get a Feast stack as soon as Feast is back up, unless you know that a team fight is imminent. The more damage you can take before you have to run away, the better, and Feast stacks will help you do that.

## AP Cho'Gath

AP Cho'Gath is not the optimal way to play Cho'Gath, to be honest. It's fun, for sure (he's one of my favorite champions), but he's not going to be effective in a truly competitive game. For this reason, I think the specifics of timing Feast when running this build aren't *as* important.

The only difference between AP Cho'Gath and Tanky Cho'Gath in terms of Feast timing is that you might want to be a *little* more conservative spamming it on minions when you are trying to go for kills. You still want to build stacks, but if you think you might be able to get a kill, then save the Feast for that. Just don't save it too long. You want to be using Feast so that you can use it again ASAP.

## Other Stuff

If you know you're about to die, and you have minions available to Feast, you need to make a quick decision. You're going to lose half your stacks either way.

If you have an *even* number of stacks:

- Don't bother feasting a minion.
- If there's an enemy nearby, and you're a high level (enough that it'll cool down by the time you respawn anyway), just Feast the nearest enemy champion so hopefully your team can avenge you.

If you have an *odd* number of stacks:

- Feast the nearest enemy minion. You'll have 1 more stack after you respawn, which will help you get up faster.

Additionally, if Feast is up when you spawn, glance at your own jungle (even if you're not the jungler) to see if there's a safe Feast choice. **The sooner you Feast, the sooner you can Feast again.**

Comment: I agree with this for tanky cho but he wants to know about when he's playing AP cho meaning he WILL be trying to deal the most damage.

Comment: @Katustrawfic I should probably read :(

Comment: @Katustrawfic - exactly, my question was framed in the context of playing AP Cho (for fun in low level games). A build like this - http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/s4-2200elo-instakill-dfg-chogath-mid-diamond-rank-339461

Comment: Even though the question was about AP cho, Tanky cho is what you should be playing top given the current meta. But if you want your team to hate you or you're just playing for fun feel free to ap top

Comment: Eh, I don't think that AP Cho is that bad a pick.  It is a niche counter pick and I would only play it mid (or maybe jungle) and never top (which I guess is what the question was about).  And I agree that tanky Cho is more general.  But I could see AP Cho as a situational play at any level other than professional play.

Comment: I don't see how AP Cho is bad in the current meta. Can you explain?

Comment: No solid reason the why or the how, but my buddy likes AP/mid Cho a lot, and he is always feasting minions. He has a tendency to not die, though, so by the time the teamfight phase rolls around, he's got six stacks and ult up, ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

The cooldown isnt that long, with that said, your lane partner can play much more aggressively with your feast on cooldown since it is a large portion of post-6 Cho's damage.

Use your feast to gain stacks simply when the enemy isnt in a position to all-in you right afterwards.  These factors obviously depend on the champion you are facing against.

If you end up in a position where your feast would have killed someone during a duel, first you have to be asking "Why did I choose this fight knowing that I did not have feast", then you should be curious how you managed to win the trade to begin with, assuming you arent dead.

Comment: +1 Good point about lane opponent knowing feast is on cooldown. Also good point to use feast when opponent is not in position for a duel!

Answer (score 2):

I main Cho'Gath (even though I prefer playing him midlane, which implies a much more AP and less tanky build).

Especially during the lane phase you don't really need your ultimate that often, if you eat a minion before recalling half of the cooldown will be gone before you return to your lane.

Also, even if you use your ultimate on minions and then you don't have it to finish your lane opponent he still is forced to recall since he'll be low health and you can still get a big gold advantage (unless you're extremely low health or you fear a gank you can usually stay in lane and farm, healing yourself with your passive)

My rule of thumb is to save my ulti if there's a possibility I'll need it in the next 15-20 seconds to kill an opponent (either because he will engage me or because I'm planning to all in), otherwise getting a stack on a minion is better.

The problem is when you die lategame and lose 3 of your 6 stacks, if you're building AP your 950-1050 true damage are very useful in a teamfight (you can wipe away their adc with a Q-W-R combo usually) so it is riskier to use it on minions if you think there will be a teamfight

Comment: +1 - Bonus question - Do you max Q or W first in your typical build?

Comment: It depends on my opponent, against champions with a long combo or a lot of mobility I max my W first because it is a safer source of damage (for example against leblanc) but I max my Q against most champions